# Memcpy exception when integrating Casablanca code into an existing C++ solution

Tags: c++, memcpy

I am using VS2010 and Casablanca version 1.2 to integrate a REST interface into an existing C++ solution. If I create a new solution with only this block of code it works flawlessly. When I drop this code into an existing .cpp file it crashes on the create of the client object with a memcpy exception. I have done the updates the properties file to look at the correct version of Casablanca (100) and added my external dependencies as well the paths for the include and lib directories.

The block of code is:

```
try 
{
    http_client_config cimconfig;
    cimconfig.set_validate_certificates(false);

    http_client cimclient(L"https://dmaid52.corp.global/workplace",cimconfig);

    cimclient .request(methods::GET).then([](http_response response) {
        string_t theResponse = response.to_string();
    }).wait();
}
catch( const http_exception &e )
{
    printf("Exception status code %u returned. %s\n", e.error_code(), e.what());
}
```

When the cimclient is created I get the exception. If I remove the references to the config and only call `http_client cimclient(L"https://dmaid52.corp.global/workplace")` it seems to work OK but then it will throw the exception on the `.request`.

The call stack for the exception is below.

```
msvcr100d.dll!_VEC_memcpy(void * dst, void * src, int len) + 0x46 bytes
cpprest100d_1_2.dll!_wmemcpy() + 0x31 bytes 
cpprest100d_1_2.dll!std::char_traits<wchar_t>::copy() + 0x2f bytes 
cpprest100d_1_2.dll!     std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> ::assign() + 0xb7 bytes 
cpprest100d_1_2.dll!    std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> ::basic_string<    wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >() + 0x86 bytes 
cpprest100d_1_2.dll!web::http::client::credentials::credentials() + 0x67 bytes 
cpprest100d_1_2.dll!web::http::client::http_client_config::http_client_config() + 0x6c bytes 
cpprest100d_1_2.dll!  web::http::client::details::_http_client_communicator::_http_client_communicator() + 0x73 bytes cpprest100d_1_2.dll!web::http::client::details::winhttp_client::winhttp_client() + 0x52 bytes 
cpprest100d_1_2.dll!std::tr1::_Ref_count_obj<web::http::client::details::winhttp_client>::_Ref_count_obj<web::http::client::details::winhttp_client><web::http::uri const &,web::http::client::http_client_config const &>() + 0xa6 bytes 
cpprest100d_1_2.dll!std::tr1::make_shared<web::http::client::details::winhttp_client,web::http::uri const &,web::http::client::http_client_config const &>() + 0x8f bytes 
cpprest100d_1_2.dll!web::http::client::http_network_handler::http_network_handler() + 0x70 bytes 
cpprest100d_1_2.dll!std::tr1::_Ref_count_obj<web::http::client::http_network_handler>::_Ref_count_obj<web::http::client::http_network_handler><web::http::uri const &,web::http::client::http_client_config const &>() + 0xa3 bytes 
cpprest100d_1_2.dll!std::tr1::make_shared<web::http::client::http_network_handler,web::http::uri const &,web::http::client::http_client_config const &>() + 0x8c bytes 
cpprest100d_1_2.dll!web::http::client::http_client::build_pipeline() + 0x6f bytes 
cpprest100d_1_2.dll!web::http::client::http_client::http_client() + 0x74 bytes 
Hl7.exe!CChartSchedule::sendScheduleToCIM(QMsgSchedule * pMsg) Line 146 + 0x35 bytes C++
```

I have searched high and low to try and find a solution to this error with no avail. I think it may be a setting somewhere in the project settings but I have compared the stand alone project to my integrated project and can't come up with anything.

Comment: What is the actual exception (i.e. read or write and at what address)?

Answer (score 0):

I've got myself into very similar situation.

In my case the problem was in different build settings for casablanca library and target executable. Casablanca was built in a static library with one set of defines and final project used other set of defines. This caused different sizes of internal structures in casablanca, which lead to very weird behavior and unexpected results.

Visual Studio gave me this error: `Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun.`

I found the source of a problem by checking `sizeof(http_client_config)` in my project and in casablanca project.

Resolution is simple - set same defines in both projects.